# How do some companies distribute beta iOS apps to a limited set of users?

Tags: ios, app-store

Testflight is one way, but it's not really very convenient for the people checking out the app. There's also the 100 user limit that you run into.

But there's http://grid.binarythumb.com/, who is distributing their app by texting a link to users. No app store involved. How are they doing this? They never collected my UDID or anything...

Comment: Hmmm... That's really strange. I can't think of any official way that you can distribute apps to users. Maybe the "Share IPA" feature in Xcode Organizer after you Archive your app?

Comment: How big do you want the limited set to be? The 100 device limit (it's not a not 100 user limit) is big enough for most developers. If you are interested in beta testing, I'm wondering why that wouldn't be enough? I don't think of beta testing as for "people checking out the app." I think of it as for people dedicated to testing the app and providing feedback. Are you looking for a way to try-before-you-by rather than beta testing?

Answer (score 0):

Apple allows unlimited distribution through apple enterprise developer account https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

But i guess that shouldn't be distributed out of the company clients.